# MYSQL Insert button on click

Tags: reactjs, express

I am using React / Express.
I've written an API that handles Get and Post properly but Put is not working
I have a button - on click I set values, on blur saveRecord (CONST) - it does not insert and I get no error in console

I expected the on click to insert a record and then allow my form to display the "dummy" transaction and allow to be changed.  The change (POST) should work

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.